# \framebreak doesn't work

Tags: beamer

I was using `beamer` in TeXstudio. I tried `\framebreak` to insert new slide in the same frame. 
But it seems it doesn't work, actually it is even showing error.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `biblatex` or bibliographies in general? You have tagged your question `biblatex`, yet I cannot find a mention of it, nor do I see a direct connection to the package in your question.

Comment: I have now retagged your question, as it evidently was not about `biblatex` in the first place. In future it might be helpful not to just say you get an error, but also to report it. It can also help to provide a small example that we can compile showing the error, a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864); but that is not always strictly necessary - as this question proves.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to read the Beamer Manual on frames. pp58+  Pay special attention to the allowframebreaks option.   http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/beameruserguide.pdf (Updated link 6/14/2020)
2. For your problem (I am attempting mind reading as there is not MWE) you need to start the frame which you which to 'break' with

   \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
3. Most of the difficulties Beamer users have with frame control are answered in section 8 of the Beamer manual.  I have always recommended a Beamer user read first the excellent tutorials at the beginning of the manual and then Chapter 8.  This provides the needed guidance for most of the formatting of a presentation.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Thank you.  Link updated.